# Find Control in collection - event ControlAvailable Disabled

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

In my lightswitch app i need to add a small image control to every row, when clicking on it , it should send you to a detail screen. I made the silverlight control and added it to the lightswitch app.

```
    partial void VidContentItemRessources_Loaded(bool succeeded) {
  int index = 0;

  foreach (VidContentItemRessourcesItem cust in this.VidContentItemRessources) {
    this.FindControlInCollection("ImageLinkIcon", this.VidContentItemRessources.ElementAt(index))
      .ControlAvailable += (s, e) => {
        MyLinkImage = (e.Control as LinkImage);
        MyLinkImage.MouseLeftButtonDown += MyLinkImage_MouseLeftButtonDown;

      };
    index++;
  }
}
```

But if i do this i get an error that the event control available can't be used on controls in collection ..

So i tried to do it like this

```
        LinkImage neco = this.FindControlInCollection("ImageLinkIcon", this.VidContentItemRessources.ElementAt(index)) as LinkImage;
    neco.MouseLeftButtonDown += MyLinkImage_MouseLeftButtonDown;
```

But then neco is allways null because it is trying to load the control before it's available... any solution pls ?

Comment: Sounds like your method VidContentItemRessources_Loaded is called too early. Try to place your code attaching the mouse event handler at least after calling InitializeComponent();

Comment: this InitializeComponent(); is inside silverlight control, i cant manage from silverlight lightswitch entities , i have to do it inside lightswich where is no InitializeComponent();

Answer (score 0):

These types of initialisations should go in the screen's *Created* method, that way you're guaranteed that all of the controls on the screen have been created. If any of the screen's methods (like *InitializeDataWorkspace*, *Created*, *Saving* etc) aren't in your code file, you can create them by using the *Write Code* dropdown box in the screen editor.

Comment: Hi Yann The Lord Of Lightswitch!! You are my great teacher !!  i solved this really bad way with dispatcher timer for now but i have nother issue :-/ i cant overtype this.FindControlInCollection("MyControl", this.Collection.ElementAt(index)); to any type which could handle mouseDown event... for now its look like i cant make myControl types from Controls in collection ?? then handle whatever on them.

Comment: My second idea is to solve this issue directly from silverlight control ... i can acces the Item Unid but i really dont know how to open new screen from lightswitch - and that should be my final result to click on icon and open its item detail screen thx fort anything ... !!

Comment: You can't get to the Silverlight control directly from the proxy that FindControl gives you. You have to add a ControlAvailable handler using the proxy. In the handler you have access to the control through the "e" parameter (using e.Control). This you can cast to the underlying Silverlight control. So if it's a DataGrid, you'd cast e.Control to a DataGrid.

Comment: Thank you for help ! i solved it the way i answerd becouse than i just create some method which i call on screen code :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:
I catching click event in silverlight control than i invoking method in lightsiwtch

```
   public void MouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
      var objDataContext = (IContentItem)this.DataContext;
      var Screen = (Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client.IScreenObject)objDataContext.Screen;

      Screen.Details.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
        Screen.Details.Methods["DoImageLinkEvent"]
              .CreateInvocation(null).Execute();
      });
    }
```